# How to aggregate multiple JavaRX Observables

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a list of Observables and I want to know when they have all completed. In particular I want to know if they all completed successfully or any one of them had an error. All observables in the list should be completed before the successful or error notification executes. I don't need any information about the results or errors in these notifications.

I tried the Observable.merge(list) but it stops with the first error.

Desired example

```
Observable.all(listOfObservables)
    .onSuccess(() -> {}) // only called if all completed successfully
    .onError(() -> {}) // only called after all completed and at least one errored
    .onComplete(() -> {}; // called after all completed regardless of success or error
```

This seems like a standard behavior; other 'async promise' like frameworks support this. Does JavaRx support this behavior? What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `mergeDelayError`. It merges multiple Observables, the same as `merge`, but its JavaDoc says - Flattens *N* Observables into one Observable, in a way that allows an Observer to receive all successfully emitted items from all of the source Observables without being interrupted by an error notification from one of them.
So the error emissions by the source Observables don't terminate the product Observable. So:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(listOfObservables)
  .subscribe(
    (v) -> {}, // for every successfull item
    (e) -> {}, // after all completed and at least one errored
    () -> {}  // after all completed, won't be called on error though
  );
```